# Pls correct these functions of float number (type: double) under binary form in delphi

Tags: delphi-xe2

I've written 2 functions to convert a float number into/from binary, but the result is incorrect. Please help me to find its bug. (I found some FAQ for this topic, but they was written for C/C++)

```
function MyFloatToBin(d: double): String;
var
  d_ptr: ^Int64;
  d_str: string;
  i: Integer;
  ch: char;
begin
  d_ptr:= @d;
  d_str:= '';
  for i:= 0 to 63 do begin
    if (d_ptr^ and (1 shl i)) > 0 then
      ch:= '1'
    else
      ch:= '0';
    d_str:= d_str + ch;
  end;
  Result:= 'F' + d_str;
end;

function MyBinToFloat: Double;
var
  d_str: String;
  i64: Int64;
  d_ptr: ^double;
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  d_str:= pop;
  len:= length(d_str);
  if (pos('F', d_str) <> 1)and(len <> 65) then begin
    push(d_str);
    exit;
  end;
  i64:= 0;
  for i:= 2 to len do
    if d_str[i] = '1' then
      i64:= i64 or (1 shl (i - 2));
  d_ptr:= @i64;
  Result:= d_ptr^;
end;
```

Using

```
temp: string;
f: double;

temp:= MyFloatToBin(pi);//pi = 3.14....
f:= MyBinToFloat(temp);//result at f is 0
```

I wonder the variable **f should be 3.14... but..**???
Please help me correct them.
Thanks

Comment: You can do this yourself by debugging. Compare the execution of each program, when given the same input, until you see where the programs diverge. For sure somebody can do it for you but surely it's more productive if you learn how to debug. It's such a critical skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is essentially the mask computation. You do `1 shl I` which gives a 32 bit value. You must do `UInt64(1) shl I` to get a 64 bit value.

Here is your code fixed:

```
function MyFloatToBinString(d: double): String;
var
    VP : ^UInt64;
    I  : Integer;
begin
    VP  := @d;
    Result := 'F';
    for I := 63 downto 0 do begin
        if (VP^ and (UInt64(1) shl I)) <> 0 then
            Result := Result + '1'
        else
            Result := Result + '0';
    end;
end;

function MyBinStringToFlat(S : String) : Double;
var
    V : UInt64;
    I : Integer;
    J : Integer;
begin
    if (Length(S) <> 65) or ((S[1] <> 'F') and (S[1] <> 'f')) then
        raise Exception.Create('Invalid format');

    V := 0;
    for I := 65 downto 2 do begin
        case S[I] of
        '1': V := V or (UInt64(1) shl (65 - I));
        '0': { Nothing to do };
        else
            raise Exception.Create('Invalid format');
        end;
    end;
    Result := PDouble(@V)^;
end;
```

And if you want to test:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    V1 : Double;
    V2 : Double;
    S  : String;
begin
    V1 := 3.1416;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(PUInt64(@V1)^));
    S := MyFloatToBinString(V1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    V2 := MyBinStringToFlat(S);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(V2.ToString);
end;
```